# Simplest way to upload a file to an up to date MediaWiki instance with Python?

Tags: python, api, post, python-requests, mediawiki

Lately I've come across a number of questions and articles very briefly covering using `urllib`, `requests`, `mwapi`, `poster`, and various other tools to either perform an HTTP POST, or working with the API to upload one or more files to a MediaWiki instance.  Thus far, nothing has worked.

So, could someone kindly provide a simple code block that will reliably upload a file to such a Wiki? My preference is in Requests and/or Python 3, but at this point I'm pretty desperate and am open to almost anything.

**Edit:**
Per the request in the comments, below is the last bit of code I attempted. It completes with no errors, but of course no file is uploaded or any change to the Wiki logs.

```
from urllib.parse import quote
import requests

user = 'username'
passw = quote('password')

baseurl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8020/mediawiki/'
apiurl = baseurl + 'api.php'
login_params = '?action=login&lgname=%s&lgpassword=%s&format=json'% (user, passw)

# Login request
r1 = requests.post(apiurl+login_params)
login_token = r1.json()['login']['token']

# Login confirm
login_params2 = login_params+'&lgtoken=%s'% login_token
r2 = requests.post(apiurl+login_params2, cookies=r1.cookies)

# Get edit token
params3 = '?format=json&action=query&meta=tokens&continue='
r3 = requests.get(apiurl+params3, cookies=r2.cookies)
edit_token = r3.json()['query']['tokens']['csrftoken']

edit_cookie = r2.cookies.copy()
edit_cookie.update(r3.cookies)

# Upload file
with open('91.png', 'rb') as f:
    headers = {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}
    payload = {'action': 'upload', 'filename': 'Image', 'file': '91.png', 'token': edit_token}
    files = {'files': f}
    r4 = requests.post(apiurl, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files, cookies=edit_cookie)
```

Comment: Start [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Upload) and show us a *specific* example of code which tries to use the API but does not work, including any error messages.

Comment: @Kevin Sadly that article hadn't gotten me very far before I posted on here. I've included a code sample.

Comment: Well the *simplest* way is to open `Special:Upload` in a browser. Can you clarify your requirements?

Comment: @Tgr Perhaps you should read the question details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the one I hadn't tried worked. Using the documented examples for `mwclient`, uploading was successful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad you got `mwclient` to work, but I think I can answer your preference of using just Python 3 and `requests`.

I was having major headaches doing the same thing, and finally got the following to work. I also posted it at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API_talk:Upload#Python_with_requests but since this was a question I found while trying to solve my problem, I'll reproduce below...

You probably strictly speaking do not need a BotPassword, but it's a good idea.

```
import requests

api_url = 'https://project/w/api.php'

USER,PASS=u'BotUsername@Instancename',u'[[Special:BotPasswords]] password' 
#Ensure bot instance is permissioned for createeditmovepage, uploadfile, uploadeditmovefile

FILENAME='/path/to/file'
REMOTENAME='remote_filename.ext'
USER_AGENT='Descriptive User Agent per [[:meta:User-Agent_policy]]'


# get login token and log in
payload = {'action': 'query', 'format': 'json', 'utf8': '', 
           'meta': 'tokens', 'type': 'login'}

r1 = requests.post(api_url, data=payload)
login_token=r1.json()['query']['tokens']['logintoken']

login_payload = {'action': 'login', 'format': 'json', 'utf8': '', 
           'lgname': USER, 'lgpassword': PASS, 'lgtoken': login_token}

r2 = requests.post(api_url, data=login_payload, cookies=r1.cookies)
cookies=r2.cookies.copy()

# We have now logged in and can request edit tokens thusly:

def get_edit_token(cookies):
        edit_token_response=requests.post(api_url, data={'action': 'query',
                                                    'format': 'json', 
                                                    'meta': 'tokens'}, cookies=cookies)
        return edit_token_response.json()['query']['tokens']['csrftoken']

# Now actually perform the upload:

upload_payload={'action': 'upload', 
            'format':'json',
            'filename':REMOTENAME, 
            'comment':'<MY UPLOAD COMMENT>',
            'text':'Text on the File: page... description, license, etc.',
            'token':get_edit_token(cookies)}

files={'file': (REMOTENAME, open(FILENAME,'rb'))}

headers={'User-Agent': USER_AGENT}

upload_response=requests.post(api_url, data=upload_payload,files=files,cookies=cookies,headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, it seems weird that your last code didn't error. Assuming that you set up MediaWiki with the standard configuration, api.php is in `baseurl/w/api.php`, not `baseurl/api.php`. This means that you requested the wrong page all the time. Try again, but this time replace `apiurl = baseurl + 'api.php'` with `apiurl = baseurl + 'w/api.php'`.

Comment: No, I have configured the local Wiki to match a workplace one that the script is meant for. Up to `#Upload File`, everything works fine, as I can create articles and post text to them. The failure is the remaining part.